# 16 bit Binary conversion

Tags: python, floating-point, binary

I have found several ways to convert both Integer and Float values to binary, and they each have their issues. I need to take an Integer/Float input **between values of 0 and 10,000**, convert to **a 16-digit (exactly) binary string**, manipulate the bits at random, and convert back to an Integer/Float (depending on the parameter).

However, I have been using the following code:

```
def convert_to_binary(value):
    '''
    Converts a float to a 16-bit binary string.
    '''
    [d] = struct.unpack('>Q', struct.pack('>d', value))
    return str('{:016b}'.format(d))

def convert_back(bin_num):
    ''' 
    Converts binary string to a float. 
    '''
    print type(bin_num) 
        print bin_num
    bf = int_to_bytes(int(bin_num, 2), 8)  # 8 bytes needed for IEEE 754 binary64.
        print struct.unpack('>d', bf)[0]
    return struct.unpack('>d', bf)[0]

#   return struct.unpack('d', struct.pack('Q', bin_num))[0]
    #bin_num.pack('B*').unpack('g').first

def int_to_bytes(n, minlen=0):  # Helper function
    '''
    Turns integer/long to byte string.
    '''
    nbits = n.bit_length() + (1 if n < 0 else 0)  # +1 for any sign bit.
    nbytes = (nbits+7) // 8  # Number of whole bytes.
    b = bytearray()
    for _ in range(nbytes):
        b.append(n & 0xff)
        n >>= 8
    if minlen and len(b) < minlen:  # Zero padding needed?
        b.extend([0] * (minlen-len(b)))
    return bytearray(reversed(b))  # High bytes first.
```

And the result is this (in picture form since I couldn't copy and paste from my terminal):

[image: this]

I understand that there are different types of binary (signed/unsigned, different bit numbers, etc.), but **I need my output to be what I *think* is unsigned short... all of my numbers are positive values, and to allow for the bit manipulation I later use, they need to be exactly 16 digits long** --> (If they are float values, I can use the extra digits of binary but just alter the first 16, and the ones that follow are just what follows the decimal point, right?)

Firstly, should I write functions for both a Float input and an Integer input?

Secondly, how do I change my code to allow for the desired output without simply using `pop`, etc. to cut the length of the binary to 16?

Comment: How do you expect a floating point value to fit into 16 bits? The standard representations are 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: In the original post, I explained it badly (`If they are float values, I can use the extra digits of binary but just alter the first 16`) - what I meant by that was that I aim to simply take the first 16 digits to mutate and then append the remaining 16. It's not a perfect system, but it introduces a bit of randomness to the overall value.

Comment: "and the ones that follow are just what follows the decimal point, right?" => IEEE 754 floating point values don't work like that...  For example, a 32-bit float has 1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits, and then 23 fraction bits such that 1.<fraction>*(2^<exponent>) yields the floating point number.  Taking the first 16 bits of that would just get you the sign bit, the exponent, and part of the fraction.  Or the last 16 bits of the fraction, depending on how you split it.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and I found a simpler and shorter solution.

Here's an example:

### Encode:

```
In [1]: val = 15

In [2]: bin_ = '{0:016b}'.format(val)
In [3]: bin_
Out[3]: '0000000000001111'
```

Or:

```
In [4]: bin_ = bin(val)[2:].zfill(16)
In [5]: bin_
Out[5]: '0000000000001111'
```

---

### Decode:

```
In [6]: int(bin_, 2)
Out[6]: 15
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very popular question to answer, I can see, so I'll put this up in the meantime:

```
def convert_to_binary(value):
    '''
    Converts a float to a 16-bit binary string.
    '''
    n = ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
    value = int(value)
    if value > 2**15:
        if value > 2**16:
            print "Value too large"
        else:
            n[0] = '1'
            value = value - (2**15)
    if value > 2**14:
        n[1] = '1'
        value = value - (2**14)
    if value > 2**13:
        n[2] = '1'
        value = value - (2**13)
    if value > 2**12:
        n[3] = '1'
        value = value - (2**12)
    if value > 2**11:
        n[4] = '1'
        value = value - (2**11)
    if value > 2**10:
        n[5] = '1'
        value = value - (2**10)
    if value > 2**9:
        n[6] = '1'
        value = value - (2**9)
    if value > 2**8:
        n[7] = '1'
        value = value - (2**8)
    if value > 2**7:
        n[8] = '1'
        value = value - (2**7)
    if value > 2**6:
        n[9] = '1'
        value = value - (2**6)
    if value > 2**5:
        n[10] = '1'
        value = value - (2**5)
    if value > 2**4:
        n[11] = '1'
        value = value - (2**4)
    if value > 2**3:
        n[12] = '1'
        value = value - (2**3)
    if value > 2**2:
        n[13] = '1'
        value = value - (2**2)
    if value > 2**1:
        n[14] = '1'
        value = value - (2**1)
    if value >= 2**0:
        n[15] = '1'
        value = value - (2**0)

        n = ''.join(n)
        n = str(n)

        print str(n)
        return str(n)

def convert_back(bin_num):
    """
    Converts binary string to a float.
    """
    value = 0
    print type(bin_num)
    n = list(bin_num)

    if n[0] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 15)
    if n[1] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 14)
    if n[2] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 13)
    if n[3] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 12)
    if n[4] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 11)
    if n[5] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 10)
    if n[6] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 9)
    if n[7] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 8)
    if n[8] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 7)
    if n[9] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 6)
    if n[10] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 5)
    if n[11] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 4)
    if n[12] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 3)
    if n[13] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 2)
    if n[14] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 1)
    if n[15] == '1':
        value = value + (2 ** 0)

    print value

    return value
```